# Validators do not Validate after postback occurs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I found the source of the issue i did not explain it very well.

Basically i have a form with a compare validator that makes sure my txtstartdate is not less than my txtenddate. So these 2 text boxes have ajax calendar attached to it and when I select those 2 my compare validator appears and gives an error.

Then i have 2 dropdownlist ddlroom, ddlnumber. ddlroom has autopostback enabled so if i populate my calendar incorrectly having my endate before startdate the comparevalidator fires however the second i select a roomname the autopostback occurs and the validator dissapears and I am able to click the insert button and it will insert what ever date is in the textboxes without validating. Hope that explains a little better sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want validation to fire when your DropDownList does a postback then be sure to set `CausesValidation="true"` on the DropDownList.

Comment: I tried enabling that on the ddlroomname and on my startdate and enddate but once the postback occurs the validator disappears and you are able to submit the record to the database and the comparevalidator does not fire